# Issue with disabling 32-Bit applications on AppPool

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, x86, assemblies

We have a website that is developed on ASP.NET Web Forms.

The website has been running with an AppPool which allows 32-Bit application. For a long time.

**(Enable 32-Bit Applications = True)**

For some reasons, now we need to disable 32-Bit application on AppPool.

I've tried to disable it, and the result is weird, that the AppPool crashed and stopped working automatically after few hours. And the website stopped working untill I start the AppPool manually.

Then, I looked thought every DLL that powers the website, including the third party libraries. I used **CorFlags** for this purposes. And didn't find any 32-Bit assembly. All the assemblies are either 64-Bit, or AnyCPU that has no problem with running on 64-Bit processes.

Then I've checked the website's Virtual Directories and Applications. There is no 32-Bit assemblies either.

So, I'm really stuck on this. I need to disable the 32-Bit application running on the AppPool.

**Question**

1. Is AppPool crash after disabling 32-Bit apps really related with there is a 32-Bit app/assemblies is running on the process? Is that causing the crash? I didn't find any 32-Bit assembly in whole source of the project. Where else they can be? Any other location that I need to look for an 32-Bit assembly?
2. What else is there that I need to investigate in order to diagnose the problem? Let's say I don't find any 32-Bit assemblies, what else can be a reason of the AppPool crash after disabling the 32-Bit applications?

Thanks everybody.

Comment: Does any of the .NET stuff use old-style (C/C++) DLLs?  If those DLLs are 32-bit, then you'll get a crash if called from a 64-bit process (in which case, the .NET DLL/EXE should be marked as 32-bit using corflags).

Comment: There are those kind of DLLs (C/C++), but they are not 32-Bit. I've checked with CorFlags, and in the result message, number next to 32 bit is `0`.

Comment: If corflags is giving you a value for `32BIT` then they are not the type of DLLs I'm talking about.  Running coflags on a non-manged DLL gives: `corflags : error CF008 : The specified file does not have a valid managed header`

Comment: Then there is no those type of DLL you are talking about. Because I've not seen any of this error message while I check the DLLs with CorFlags. In all the cases I'm getting a meaningful result.

Comment: I only have limited experience of ASP.NET and application pools, so there may be many other reasons for your problem, but if it **is** to do with unmanged DLLs, one last thing you could try is to run `ILDASM OneOfYour.DLL`.  Open the `M A N I F E S T` entry and if there are any non-managed DLLs these should be listed as `.module extern ThirdParty.dll`.

Comment: did u ever figure this one?  I know  it's 5 years...just run into this problem myself.